# AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'mainloop'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.title("US State Game")
screen.bgpic("blank_states_img.gif")

def get_cor(x, y):
    print(x, y)

turtle.onclick(get_cor)
turtle.mainloop()
```

AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'mainloop'

I am tring to get cordinates(x & y) by clicking on the window.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling mainloop() on the Turtle object.
replace turtle.mainloop() with screen.mainloop():

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.title("US State Game")
screen.bgpic("blank_states_img.gif")

def get_cor(x, y):
    print(x, y)

turtle.onclick(get_cor)
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a turtle object with the name of turtlle hence the error. Rename the variable and it should work here:

```
import turtle
tur = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("US State Game")
screen.bgpic("blank_states_img.gif")

def get_cor(x, y):
    print(x, y)

turtle.onclick(get_cor)
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: That part of the OP's code was perfectly valid, the problem was in the call to `mainloop()` as @AlonAlush noted.  His correction to the OP's code uses `turtle` as a variable name without issue.